# How can we create Azure's Data Factory pipeline with Neo4jDB (with Graph) as data sink ? (data source being OracleDB )

Tags: oracle, azure, neo4j, azure-data-factory

In the Azure environment, I have to copy data from OracleDb by using copy activity and a Neo4j Graph sink location.Using an Azure Data Factory, I need to insert/update data from the Oracledb to the GraphDb.

My thinking is that I need to first transform the data to json and from there insert it into the GraphDb.how to do this ?

In the Azure environment, I have to copy data from OracleDb by using copy activity and a Neo4j Graph sink location.Using an Azure Data Factory, I need to insert/update data from the Oracledb to the GraphDb.

My thinking is that I need to first transform the data to json and from there insert it into the GraphDb.how to do this ?

Comment: I don't think there is a specific connector for Neo4jDB. Refer to this MS documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview

Answer (score 0):

- There might not be any specific sink connector for `Neo4j GraphDB` in azure data factory. In general, to achieve your requirement, copy data activity should be helpful.
- You can read your data from Oracle DB in copy data source using the required connector.

[image]

- But there is no sink support for `Neo4j Graph DB`. You can refer to this official [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview) to check all the supported source and sink connectors for different activities. You can raise the feature request for this sink connector [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/1219ec2d-6c26-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f032c).

[image]